# Programmatically added LinearLayouts not equally spaced

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having some spacing trouble when building part of my UI programmatically in Android 4.0.  I am trying to add stylized buttons to a stylized LinearLayout.  To space the buttons equally, each one is wrapped in a LinearLayout with a weight of 1.  I started with a layout defined in XML (somewhat of a proof of concept,) which renders like I expect:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/dialog_footer" 
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_footer">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:id="@+id/cancel"
            style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Another LinearLayout with a nested Button like the one above -->

</LinearLayout>
```

To add buttons programmatically, I removed the inner LinearLayouts and put them in their own layout file that I can inflate and add to the outer LinearLayout in Java.  It is nearly identical.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is roughly how I'm adding buttons in code:

```
LinearLayout dialogFooter = (LinearLayout)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_footer);
LinearLayout wrappedButton = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_button_wrapped, null);

Button button = (Button)wrappedButton.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setText(R.string.button_one_text);

// button.setOnClickListener(...);

dialogFooter.addView(wrappedButton);
```

The buttons appear but now they are grouped together and shifted to the left.  Is there something Android does when it parses a Layout that I would need to do myself if I'm adding to the dialog_footer?  Since weights come into play here, I thought that calling setWeightSum() on the container I'm adding to (dialog_footer) might be necessary but that didn't help.  Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing the difference between the XML and Java approaches?

Comment: try printing out the coordinates and see whether they match up with the actual placement

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe this is your problem:

```
LinearLayout wrappedButton = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_button_wrapped, null);
```

The null should be replaced with the parent view , so that it will get the layoutParams you want to set for it .

Another thing is about the weight you set - you should set the width/height to 0px so that the weight won't cause the layout process work in a weird/inefficient way .

BTW , you can remove the inner layout (that has the button) and use a single button instead. just set the layout_gravity there to center_horizontal .

Comment: Good catch.  Giving the parent when inflating (and not adding it to the parent later) was just what I wanted.  I have some other small layout issues now but that worked.  I'm not sure about the last recommendation though.  If I remove the inner LinearLayout, center_horizontal will center them horizontally (leaving them alone vertically) but the buttons will still be pushed together in center of their parent (what was the outer LinearLayout.)  The idea of the inner LinearLayouts is that they divide the entire width of the parent and then the buttons are center in those.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: it's ok , only you know what you want to do . i only guessed what could be done. maybe i'm wrong about it . it was just a suggestion. in general , you should try to avoid adding layouts that have a single item in them . the more layouts , the more time it takes to inflate and measure things . maybe Lint can help you with good tips of your code (you run it by pressing the checkbox "V" button at the upper toolbar of eclipse,near the sdk manager button) .

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with your recommendation regarding the inner LinearLayout - just trying to understand it.  To my (admittedly small) knowledge, removing the inner layouts and setting the outer layout's gravity to center_horizontal won't space out the nested buttons - it will just center them horizontally, won't it?  I wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Comment: no , it's me who didn't understand what you need , so i should have given a more general suggestion . i'm sorry . for performance , i suggest that you try to avoid such a thing by trying out some other solutions . of course , if it's all static and not inside a listView or something that moves, you can definitely let it stay the way it is, if it fits your needs.

Comment: Does capitalization offend you?